# CareerBuilder Job Posting Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

So, I got a dev key from CareerBuilder and I am looking to post a job on their site trough their API. However, so far I have only found ways to retrieve job posting based on certain criteria. Is there a way I can post a job on their site given provided information? (preferably using C# unless there is only one way)

Comment: share what you have, like web service link and the way you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CareerBuilder does not publicly expose their job posing API. Posting is about the only thing you cannot do via their API.

You can see all of the exposed endpoints for the API here: http://developer.careerbuilder.com/endpoints/index#collapse4

However, if you want to be able to post a job from CareerBuilder and don't want to use the web site CareerBuilder does offer you some options there.

You can use their Document Post Interface (DPI). Information can be found here: http://dpi.careerbuilder.com/Site/Index.aspx

The DPI will get you what you want but it is completely separate from the API. You will need to talk to your sales rep or account manager if you are interested in posting via the DPI.

If you do not have a sales rep or account manager, you can call their 1-800 number and they can get you the information there.

Unfortunately I don't believe there is a lot of public information about the DPI. I'm a former employee of CareerBuilder and used to work on their DPI and mapping platforms.

UPDATE: Remembered this after posting. You can also email IntegrationSupport@careerbuilder.com to find more information. That email address is more for technical support but they can point you in the right direction.